# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple (when trying to print even columns of matrix)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new here and i have such problem:
I need to print even columns of matrix. When i tried to do this i've got such error:

```
print(array[:, 1::2])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Here is what i tried to solve this problem:

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr = []
rows = int(input('\nInput the number of rows: '))
cols = int(input('Input the number of cols: '))


def AutoFill(rand_arr, rows, cols):
    for k in range(rows):
        arr = []
        for v in range(cols):
            a = random.randint(-20, 20)
            arr.append(a)
        rand_arr.append(arr)
    rand_arr = np.array([])
    return rand_arr


def PrintArr(array):
    print('Your matrix: ')
    print(np.matrix(array))


def EvenCols(array):
    print(array[:, 1::2])


AutoFill(arr, rows, cols)
PrintArr(arr)
EvenCols(arr)
```

Comment: Result of `AutoFill()` is not stored anywhere, and thus `arr` on the top level remains being a list. `arr = AutoFill(arr, rows, cols)` may work better, and inside `AutoFill()` you may want `rand_arr = np.array(rand_arr)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Are you aware that you're not using the return value from `AutoFill()`? You probably meant to do `arr = AutoFill(arr, rows, cols)`, although re-using a variable name is confusing.

Comment: Are you aware of [`np.random`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html)? All of `AutoFill` (after the changes from BrokenBenchmark) could be boiled down to `return np.random.randint(-20, 20, (rows, cols))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is a vanilla Python list, not a numpy array. You can't use tuple indexing on vanilla Python lists.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. You should transform `arr` to a numpy array before you pass it into `EvenCols()`, like so:

```py
EvenCols(np.array(arr))
```

You can then remove the last two lines of the `AutoFill` function, since this method modifies the list in-place.

2. Methods that have side effects can make it harder for others to understand your code. While for this short example it may be fine, a better approach would be to create a new list, in the function, return it, and assign the function's return value to `arr`, like so:

```py
def AutoFill(rows, cols):
    rand_arr = []
    for k in range(rows):
        arr = []
        for v in range(cols):
            a = random.randint(-20, 20)
            arr.append(a)
        rand_arr.append(np.array(arr))
    return np.array(rand_arr)
```

Then, the last three lines would look like:

```py
arr = AutoFill(rows, cols)
PrintArr(arr)
EvenCols(np.array(arr))
```

Additionally, in this approach, the initial assignment to `arr` at the top of your code snippet can be removed.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me
I appreciate it!